# What is the order type of [0,1)?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

My question is pretty simple, but I want to make sure I'm understanding it correctly, because otherwise my misconception could go on a while.

What is the "order type" of [0,1)?

I know the set has a smallest element, does not have a largest element, and for any two elements in the set x < y we can find another element z so that x < z < y.

Are these the properties referred to by the phrase "order type of [0,1)"?  Is there anything I am missing?

This was inspired by a homework problem from Munkres #12 from section 24 needing to show that [a,c) has the same order type as [0,1) iff both [a,b) and [b,c) have the same order type as [0,1).

Thanks!

Comment: That does not capture it all. Two ordered sets have the same order type if they are order isomorphic.

Comment: You miss just the fact that it has the supremum property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the open interval $(0,1)$ is isomorphic to the real line, its order type is $\lambda$, the order type of the real line. The half-open interval $[0,1)$ therefore has order type $1+\lambda$; similarly, the order type of the half-open interval $(0,1]$ is $\lambda+1$, and the order type of the closed interval $[0,1]$ is $1+\lambda+1$.

> I know the set has a smallest element, does not have a largest element, and for any two elements in the set x < y we can find another element z so that x < z < y.
>   
> Are these the properties referred to by the phrase "order type of [0,1)"?

No. The set $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1)$ of all rational numbers in $[0,1)$ has all the properties you listed, but is not isomorphic to $[0,1)$ (different cardinalities), so it does not have the same order type; its order type is $1+\eta$.

Comment: Thank you!  So then like @Andre Nicolas said I need to produce a bijection preserving order between the sets to show that they have the same order type?

Comment: @AlexH: That is the definition of having the same order type. In some settings there may be indirect ways to show that two linear orders have the same order type, but they are ways to show the existence of such a bijection without actually producing one.

Comment: How would $\lambda$ be represented in terms of $omega_1$? I am asking this because when we work out the height of a tree $(T, <)$, which is the order type of ${{s ∈ T : s < t}}$, we typically give it in terms of an 'omega' ordinal (well at least that's how I've seen it)

Comment: @MathGeek The order type of the real line is not an ordin al number; I don't know what it would mean to represent it interms of omega. I don't think you can.

Comment: @bof Assuming the Axiom of Choice, the set of real numbers is a well ordering (by the well ordering theorem, which is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice). By definition, every well ordered set is order equivalent to exactly one ordinal number. So what would be this ordinal for the set of real numbers? Would it also be equivalent to $\lambda$?

Comment: @MathGeekYou asked about $\lambda$ which is not an ordinal; it is the order type of the usual ordering of the real line, which is not a well-ordering. Assuming the axiom of choice, the real numbers can be well-ordered in many different ways, corresponding to different ordinal numbers. The least possible ordinal number for a well-ordering of the real numbers **could be** $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal; that is the so-called **continuum hypothesis**.